# QR-code from jobname

Tags: macros

I would like to print a qr-code in a LaTeX documnet.
The info to the `\qrcode` command of `qrcode` package would come from the file name by the `varsfromjobname` package. But it does not work for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{varsfromjobname}

\begin{document}

\def\foo{bar}%
\def\qrinfo{\getfromjobname{2}}%
{\LARGE OK, \qrinfo\ is printable}

\qrcode{This \foo\ is working.}
\qrcode{This \qrinfo\ does not!}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

The macro `\getfromjobname` is not “fully expandable”, due to usage of `\ifthen`, so it can't be used in the argument to `\qrcode`. Using directly `\gettwofromjobname` works.

If I name the file `kinda-hanta.tex` and modify it to be

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{varsfromjobname}

\begin{document}

\def\foo{hanta}%
\def\qrinfo{\gettwofromjobname}%
{\LARGE OK, \qrinfo\ is printable}

\qrcode{This \foo\ is working.}
\qrcode{This \qrinfo\ is working.}

\end{document}
```

then the result are two identical QR-codes

[image]

The definition of `\getfromjobname` might be  modified as

```
\renewcommand{\getfromjobname}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1 \or
    \getonefromjobname\or
    \gettwofromjobname\or
    \getthreefromjobname\or
    \getfourfromjobname\or
    \getfivefromjobname\or
    \getsixfromjobname\or
    \getsevenfromjobname\or
    \geteightfromjobname\or
    \getninefromjobname
  \fi
}
```

with the catch that an erroneous argument to `\getfromjobname` wouldn't be caught (in the original macro it would print nothing).

---

Here is a fully expandable version of `\getfromjobname` based on `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% get the pieces of the file name
\seq_new:N \c_varsfromjobname_tokens_seq
\seq_set_split:NnV \c_varsfromjobname_tokens_seq { - } \c_sys_jobname_str
% the user interface
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\getfromjobname}{m}
 {
  \seq_item:Nn \c_varsfromjobname_tokens_seq { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\qrcode{This hanta is working.}
\qrcode{This \getfromjobname{2} is working.}

\end{document}
```

This even overcomes the limitation of `varsfromjobname` that allows just nine pieces.

Comment: I will add a reference to this code to the package.

Answer (score 9):

Run with `pdflatex --shell-escape ...`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document}

\pspicture(1in,1in)\psbarcode{\jobname}{}{qrcode}\endpspicture
\qquad
\pspicture(0.5in,0.5in)\psbarcode{\jobname}{format=micro}{qrcode}  \endpspicture

\end{document}
```

or with `xelatex`

[image]